# How do I detect that a windows updates is applying patches in C#

Tags: c#, windows

As the subject. How do I detect that a windows updates is applying patches in C#? I have looked through the WUApi e.g. here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nf-wuapi-iupdatesearcher-search, but it is not concerned with reporting what's going on right now

Comment: May I ask why you need this? What's the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: We have a combination of Windows Update as well as a C# Windows Service that manages the entire windows update. We need to time any restart with work that goes on on the server where we wait for work to finish before we restart. So in a thread in the Windows Service we do ISystemInformation systemInfo = new SystemInformation(); and interrogate systemInfo.RebootRequired in a timer. We have experienced though that this flag is set to true before Windows Update is done installing. So I would like to check something else as well indicating that the update is still running.